# dplyr: Downloading a file based on the values in every row of a data_frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to download a file based on the values in the rows of a `data_frame`. Here is what the `data_frame` looks like:

```
df_foo = data_frame(
  input_id = 1:10, 
  file_name_id = 20:30
)
```

Here is an attempt using `by_row` from the `purrr` package which does not work.

```
df_foo %>% 
  by_row(
    .f = download.file, 
    url = paste0("http://foobar.com/id=", input_id),
    destfile = paste0("file number", file_name_id, ".txt")
  )
```

I have also tried `invoke_rows` (`map_rows`). Any solution that would work in pipes would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `rowwise`:

```
df_foo %>%
     rowwise %>%
     do(f=download.file(paste0("http://example.com/id=", .$input_id),
                        paste0("file_", .$filename_id)))
```

But do you really need dplyr?

```
mapply(download.file, paste0("http://example.com/id=", df_foo$input_id),
                      paste0("file_", df_foo$filename_id))
```

Comment: I guess you are right -- thanks for providing both versions.